# Working with UTF-8 in Python?

Tags: python, string, encoding

I am coding something in Python and I need to ensure that the script will work for any UTF-8 string inputted via the command line. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: it should basically just work if you are using unicode python

Comment: @JoranBeasley What does that mean?

Comment: did you download the unicode version of python or the non-unicode version? your terminal would also have to support utf-8 obviously.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't know. I usually go to http://www.python.org/download/ and download 2.7 version for Python 2.7.4 Windows X86-64 Installer

Comment: There is no such thing as "unicode Python" - Python 3.x uses Unicode strings by default, but any version should work fine. In 2.x, just make sure to use `unicode` over `str`.

Comment: Whether it will "work" depends on what it does, as well as how the UTF-8 is input, which depends on the terminal encoding used for the command line.  If you're having a particular problem you'll need to show what your code is actually doing with the input.

Comment: For example I just went to one of these Related questions and tried passing in the argument string "idzie wąż wąską dróżką" but the resulting output back looks like "idzie waz waska dr\xf3zka" which I assume is wrong

Comment: I coulda sworn there were two versions and only one supported unicode ... I must be thinking of something else though because your right ... sorry :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley For Windows, pre-3.3, there is a "wide" and a "narrow" build, the latter using UTF-16 which translates into some weirdness with code points outside the BMP.

Comment: So can anyone explain what I actually need to do?

Comment: \xf3 is the codepoint for the ó ... not sure why the other characters got converted to ascii